# Compare values from two csv files (f1 & f2)and make updation in second file(f2)

Tags: shell, csv, awk

Hi friends this question might be asked before but making changes to the same file is a bit tedious for me.The data here is added every second for different parameters.I tried using `awk` `sed` `python` but don't know which technology to use.So here's my sample file and logic.

File1 f1.csv

```
P,       V,     TS
p1,     12,     10:10:00
p2,     34,     10:21:00
p1,     12,     10:21:00
p2,     34,     10:22:00   
p3,     60,     10:36:00
p1,     60,     10:35:00
p4,     22,     10:38:00
p1,     60,     10:40:00
```

Current(File2 f2.csv)

```
P,      V,      RTS,         UTS
p1,     12,    10:00:00,    10:10:00    
p2,     34,    10:18:00,    10:20:00
p1,     54,    10:20:00,    10:21:00
p2,     54,    10:22:00,    10:24:00
p3,     60,    10:31:00,    10:31:00
```

#Output can printed in the same file after making changes(f2.csv) or you can make a third file for output(f3.csv) refering file f2.csv

Expected (File f2.csv)/Output file (file f3)

```
P,      V,     RTS,         UTS
p1      12    10:10:00      10:21:00
p2      34    10:18:00      10:22:00
p1      54    10:20:00      10:21:00
p2      54    10:22:00      10:24:00
p3      60    10:31:00      10:36:00
p1      60    10:35:00      10:40:00   
p4      22    10:38:00      10:38:00
```

Logic (Pseudo Code)

```
 for each (P, V) in f1
{
   #if value exists in f2
     if ((P, V) exists in f2)
    { 
     f2.UTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V)
     } 
else
    { 
    #add new (P, V) line in f2 
    f2.RTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V) 
    f2.UTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V) 
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is your expected output. Please update your question to add that.

Comment: @jaypal i have modified the code..hope it helps..

Comment: Hello,
I don't think the pseudo code you are proposing does what you are expecting. I has to be clearer I guess. I will propose some thing for you to validate:

    `for each (P, V) in f1 {`
        `if (P, V) exists in f2 {`
            `f2.UTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V)`
        `} else {`
            `add new (P, V) line in f2`
            `f2.RTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V)`
            `f2.UTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V)`
        `}`

Comment: i have changed the pseudo code as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not understood the purpose of your script, so I will propose you a script that matches exactly your pseudo code.

Let's say that your data files are written this way:

```
> File f1.csv
    # P, V, TS
    p1, 12, 10:10:00
    p1, 22, 10:15:00
    p2, 34, 10:20:00
    p1, 54, 10:21:00
    p2, 54, 10:22:00
    p4, 54, 10:25:00
    p3, 60, 10:31:00
    p1, 45, 10:35:00

> File f2.csv
    # P, V, RTS, UTS
    p1, 12, 10:00:00, 10:10:00
    p1, 22, 10:15:00, 10:15:00
    p2, 34, 10:18:00, 10:20:00
    p1, 54, 10:20:00, 10:21:00
    p2, 54, 10:22:00, 10:24:00
    p4, 54, 10:25:00, 10:26:00
    p3, 60, 10:31:00, 10:31:00
    p4, 45, 10:35:00, 10:35:00
```

The script you are looking for is the following:

```
import numpy as np

fn1 = './f1.csv'
fn2 = './f2.csv'

# genfromtxt loads the file and understands the written format.
# In this case, it is more suitable than loadtxt.
# The file is loaded as an array of dictionaries.
t1 = np.genfromtxt(fn1, delimiter=',', comments="#",
                   names=True, dtype=None)

t2 = np.genfromtxt(fn2, delimiter=',', comments="#",
                   names=True, dtype=None)

# Well, here, you can write the conditions you want to modify the table t2
# that will be saved in the original file fn2
for i in xrange(min(len(t1), len(t2))):
    if (t1[i]['P'] == t2[i]['P'] and t1[i]['V'] == t2[i]['V']):
        t2[i]['UTS'] = t1[i]['TS']
    else:
        t2[i]['RTS'] = t2[i]['UTS'] = t1[i]['TS']

# If your are using one of the last versions of Python, you might replace
# the following three lines with only one, using the header argument:
# np.savetxt(fn2, t2, fmt=('%s', ' %d', '%s', '%s'), delimiter=',',
#            header="# P, V, RTS, UTS\n")
with open(fn2, 'wb') as f:
    f.write("# P, V, RTS, UTS\n")
    np.savetxt(f, t2, fmt=('%s', ' %d', '%s', '%s'), delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Hi, there is a mistake on your `else` clause, according to the OP pseudo-code, `t2[i]['UTS'] = t1[i]['TS']` should be done there too!

Comment: @Taha hi i have a small request the no of rows in file1 might be very large than file2.Basically file2 will have unique values from file1 if the value is new it will get inserted with same RTS & UTS else the UTS value in file2 will get updated..

Comment: @[Mr.E.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15931/mr-e).
In Python, `a = b = c` is equivalent to `a = c` and `b = c`.
I think this matches the pseudo code. Anyway, the conditions proposed in the pseudo code can be improved as shown in your answer.

Comment: @[onkark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3239459/onkark) To explain the script, the files will be read and the lines will be compared one by one. I mean, every line `i` from f1 with the line of the same index `i` in f2.
I used `for i in xrange(min(len(t1), len(t2)))`. In this case, the script will stop on the last line of the shorter data file and no exception will be raised.
May be I could advice a better solution if I understand the purpose of your script. I know that it deals with pressure, volume and time, but I don't understand the experiment.

Comment: @Taha i have modified the code.The output will give you all possible outcomes..pls ask if u need any thing else..

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify your pseudo code from

```
If (P,V from f1)==(P,V from f2)
{
    UTS from f2=TS from f1
}
elseif((P,V from f1)!=(P,V from f2))
{
    RTS from f2=TS from f1
    UTS from f2=TS from f1
}
```

to:

```
UTS from f2=TS from f1 # this is always executed anyway
If((P,V from f1)!=(P,V from f2))
{
    RTS from f2=TS from f1
}
```

Next, you have to remove the spaces between the columns on your csv file (at least on the header). This needed is because otherwise [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) would load the space as part of the header names, which is not nice.
So you have the files in the following format:

**f1.csv**

```
P,V,TS
p1,12,10:10:00
p2,34,10:20:00
p1,54,10:21:00
p2,54,10:22:00
p3,60,10:31:00
```

**f2.csv**

```
P,V,RTS,UTS
p1,12,10:00:00,10:10:00
p2,34,10:18:00,10:20:00
p1,54,10:20:00,10:21:00
p2,54,10:22:00,10:24:00
p3,60,10:31:00,10:31:00
```

Then in python you can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

f2_output = []
with open('f1.csv', 'rb') as f1:
    with open('f2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
        f1_reader = csv.DictReader(f1, delimiter = ',')
        f2_reader = csv.DictReader(f2, delimiter = ',')
        for f1row in f1_reader:
            try:
                f2row = f2_reader.next()
            except StopIteration:
                # basic check to ensure amount of rows is the same
                raise Exception('Too many rows on f1!')
            #import pdb
            #pdb.set_trace()
            f2row['UTS'] = f1row['TS']
            if f1row['P'] == f2row['P'] and f1row['V'] == f2row['V']:
                f2row['UTS'] = f1row['TS']
            f2_output.append(f2row)

        # basic check ensure that all rows on f2 were processed
        try:
            _ = f2_reader.next()
            raise Exception('Too many rows on f2!')
        except StopIteration:
            pass
header = ['P', 'V', 'RTS', 'UTS']
header_dict = dict([(x, x) for x in header])
with open('f2_out.csv', 'w') as f2_out:
    f2_out_writer = csv.DictWriter(f2_out, header, delimiter = ',')
    # if you have python >= 2.7, you can use writeheader() here
    f2_out_writer.writerow(header_dict)
    f2_out_writer.writerows(f2_output)
```

Comment: hi i have a small request the no of rows in file1 might be very large than file2.Basically file2 will have unique values from file1 if the value is new it will get inserted with same RTS & UTS else the UTS value in file2 will get updated..